# Getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException error Idenity Server4

Tags: identityserver4

We are using Entity framework core with Identity server4 and getting the ArgumentOutOfRangeException when calling the token endpoint via code. Here is our ConfigurationServices method in Identity server project:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServer");



        var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
        SecurityKey key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsaProvider);

        var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials
              (key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha512Signature);


        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddIdentityServer()
           .AddSigningCredential(credentials)
            // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            }) // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                // options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                // options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
            });

        // Add S3 to the ASP.NET Core dependency injection framework.
        services.AddAWSService<Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3>();
    }
```

Here is our client application that calling identity server project("http://localhost:3000/"):

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string client, string secret)
    {

        IActionResult result = null;

        //discover endpoints from metadata

        var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:3000/");

        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            result = NotFound(disco.Error);

            return result;
        }
        //request token

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, client, secret);

        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync(scope: "sup");

        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
        {
            result = NotFound(tokenResponse.Error);
        }

        result = Ok(tokenResponse.Json);

        return result;
    }
```

Here is error we have got:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing RSACryptoServiceProvider to RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)?

Comment: yes i have tried, actually this issue is fixed when i use SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature instead of SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256.